# MVC PartialView not rendered when passing strongly typed model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, partial-views

I'm calling a controller method using AJAX request.
This function used to return a partial view so I will load it in an HTML element.

the function:

```
public PartialViewResult LoadLockTimerEnd()
{
    Session["Info"] = new Request();
    RequestReply reqRep = new RequestReply("/Home/Index", "ID missing. Reseting");
    return PartialView("FailurePartialView", reqRep);
}
```

When passing a simple string as model to this PartialView it works fine, but when passing a RequestReply object as model it is not working and the partialView is not loaded at all.

The PatialView:

```
@model EPS_WEB_SITE.Models.RequestReply;
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_FailureLayout.cshtml";
} 
<strong>@Html.Raw(@Model.Message.ToString())</strong>
<div class="buttons-container button-container-small">
     <div data-request-url="@Model.RedirectURL.ToString()">
            <button type="button" id="dismiss-failure-btn" class="btn btn-danger dismiss">Dismiss</button>
     </div> 
</div>
```

The AJAX call:

```
$.get('/Home/LoadLockTimerEnd', function (data) {
    $("#resultDiv").html(data);
});
```

Why does the PartialView works with string as model and not class as model?

Comment: How do you call it using Ajax .. can you share the method ?

Comment: EDIT: added ajax call. I don't think the AJAX call is the problem because the code is entering the controller method but nothing happens afterwards

Comment: did you try the Answer ?

Comment: What error messages are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: And show the model and confirm that the values of both `Message` and `RedirectURL` are not `null` (although you can remove the pointless `.ToString()` on those anyway

Comment: I'm getting GET http://localhost:59332/Home/LoadLockTimerEnd 500 (Internal Server Error) in browser console

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "HTML",
    url: '/Home/LoadLockTimerEnd',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#resultDiv").html(data);
    }
});
```

Try to call your Action using this way

Comment: This is just identical to OP's code! (`$.get()` is a shortcut for `$.ajax()`)

Comment: I know, I added this because of dataType to be HTML and asked him to try it (may be this is the issue)

Comment: Both `$.ajax()` and `$.get()` will determine the `dataType` if its not supplied.

Comment: I don't know, Are you sure of that ? Something I was facing problem of return data and solving it be determine the type to be JSON, HTML .. etc

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.But since OP claims it works in other cases, its the model which is the issue.

Comment: @AhmedRagheb unfortunately your solution does not work

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found the problem:
It was a compilation error.
I needed to remove ; in the model binding in the view

```
@model EPS_WEB_SITE.Models.RequestReply;
```

I was able to find that in the network tab on Chrome browser.
Double click on the problematic request and it shown the server error.

Hope it will help someone